# Python using windows command line

Tags: python, cmd, ffmpeg

I have this python code:

```
        import os
        os.system('cd C:\yt')
        os.system("ffmpeg.exe -i test.mp4 newfilename.mp3")
```

The yt folder include the ffmeg.exe and test.mp4 but I write the code apart on cmd everthing is working but thus I get this error message:

```
       'ffmpeg.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
       operable program or batch file.
```

if I use C:\yt\ffmpeg.exe -i test.mp4 newfilename.mp3 is not working and if i use only os.system('cd C:\yt') i not get error message.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `os.system` executes commands in a subshell, which means that the second command is not executed in `C:\yt`

Comment: I reoommend: `subprocess.call("ffmpeg.exe -i test.mp4 newfilename.mp3",cwd=r"c:\yt")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move to that directory. Try the following:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\yt')
print os.getcwd() # confirm location
os.system("ffmpeg.exe -i test.mp4 newfilename.mp3")
```

Comment: it's really a bad way of running a command in a separate directory.

Comment: I'm following the OPs approach

Comment: I know, but sometimes it's better not to, or explain then provide a better approach.